# jquery json problem

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

look at this function please

```
$(".menu_tree img.edit").click(function()
    {
        id = this.id;
        lang = '<?=$lang_id?>';
        var body_width = $("body").width();
        var body_height = $("body").height();
        $("#shadow").width(body_width);
        $("#shadow").height(body_height);
        $("#shadow").show();

        var width = $("#edit_title").width();
        var height = $("#edit_title").height();
        $("#edit_title").height(0);
        $("#edit_title").width(0);
        $("#edit_title").animate(
        {
            width: width,
            height: height
        },600);
        $.post
        (
            "get_title.php",
            {id: id, lang: lang},
            function(data)
            {
                alert("qqq");
            },
            "json"
        );
    });
```

in `get_title.php` i generate json object, something like `{name:"name",val:"value"}`
it works fine if i don't wrote `"json"`, but with `"json"` it even doesn't alert my `qqq`:(

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If there is something wrong in parsing your response as json, this problem may happen. Check if your response is coming as a valid json or not...

Comment: i've checked allready, it comes in `{name:"name",val:"value"}` format.
but even it comes in wrong format, i think it must make an alert?

Comment: It is expecting a json object to be returned, if it isnt json, its not going to trigger when you explicitly state it should be json.  People are willing/trying to help you with this, but need more information to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1.4.2 parser is more strict than earlier versions. As noted by michal, that json is not valid because the property names are not double quoted.  I was bit by this issue recently when upgrading a site to  jQuery 1.4.2.

I strongly suggest allowing PHP to take care of json encoding for you.  My problem, which I suspect is yours as well, was that I was putting together json strings manually in PHP, and jQuery was rejecting it because some were single quoted.

So, for the PHP rather than something like

```
echo "{name:'$val',val:'$val'}";
exit;
```

let PHP do the encoding:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('name'=>$val,'val'=>$val));
exit;
```

also, adding a Content-Type header for JSON can't hurt if you aren't already.

Answer (score 3):

`{name: "name", val: "value" }` is not valid JSON.  The keys must also be strings.

```
{"name": "name", "val": "value"}
```